# ViewBag- MVC3-ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am tring to assign a value to ViewBag in the controller for later usage in the View, It complaines with the following error.

Assigning the value in the Controller like this.

```
 ViewBag["isAdmin"]=true;
```

Error:

```
 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'
```

Does anyone had this before?

Comment: `ViewBag` is of type `Dynamic` so you can just use dot notation. However `ViewData` is of type `Dictionary` (well ViewDataDictionary), so you have to use indexing to specify the key.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All you need is `ViewBag.isAdmin = true`. the you can access is with

```
if(ViewBag.isAdmin)
{ 
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As a follow-up, the idea behind ViewBag (and ViewData) is that you can store off key-value pairs of stuff and conveniently access them over in the View.

With ViewData, you reference these things like so:

```
ViewData["SomeKey"] = someObject;
```

If you want to do the same using the ViewBag instead (which provides a wrapping around that ViewData dictionary construct and makes it a little less verbose and a bit more readable) you reference things like so:

`ViewBag.isAdmin = true;`

and can check them, as tyrongower stated above, like so:

```
if (ViewBag.isAdmin)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

I typically use the ViewBag syntax when I do use this construct, but they really do reference the same stuff.  So if you did something like so outside the View:

`ViewData["isAdmin"] = true;`

you could reference it like this, if you were so inclined:

`ViewBag.isAdmin`

or vice-versa.

Just a little more detail on the concept.